# Weird pagination link generation - domain/domain/domain/channel/P2

Tags: structure, pagination, zoo-triggers

EE: 2.7.2
Zoo Triggers: 1.2.2

I've got a weird issue with pagination.

This is my channel entries tag.

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="news" dynamic="off" limit="1" paginate="bottom" orderby="date" sort="desc" status="open" {triggers:entries}}
```

This is the link automatically generated by pagination:

```
http://domain.dev/http://domian.dev/http://domain.dev/news/P2
```

This is my pagination code

```
{page}
    <li><a href="{pagination_url}" {if current_page}class="current"{/if}>{pagination_page_number}</a></li>
{/page}
```

---

**Pagination works when...**

If I manually go to page 2 or whatever the pagination links generate correctly.

If I use: pagination_base = "news" it works perfectly but I also use zoo triggers for categories and it doesn't work when inside a category, instead of news/category/xxxx/P2 it just goes back to news/P2

---

If anyone knows whats going on here, and why pagination links are being output like (domain)/(domain)/(domain/channel/pagination) it would help me so much.

---

**Edit**

Also using Structure 3.3.12

**Edit**

Still no answers to this

Comment: what do you have in General settings for "URL to the root directory of your site" & "Name of your site's index page" ?

Comment: URL to the root directory: `http://domain.dev`
Name of Site index: `/`